# WHERE clause in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am working to create my first API call using PowerShell.  I am curious to know, is a way to create a WHERE clause at the PowerShell level?

Below is my code which works expect that the WHERE clause does not do anything (all records still come through without error).  Note, the web request is to a public API listing holidays.

```
$Server = "TEST" 
$Database = "API_Test" 
$Conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=$Server;Database=$Database;Integrated      Security=True;")
$Conn.Open()
$cmd = $Conn.CreateCommand()

$request = 'https://date.nager.at/api/v2/publicholidays/2020/US'  
$result = Invoke-WebRequest $request  
$JSONResult = $result | ConvertFrom-Json  
$JSONResult | Select date, name Where name = 'Christmas Day' 

foreach ($obj in $JSONResult) {  
    $cmd.CommandText = "INSERT test VALUES (@Date, @Name)"  
    $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", $obj.date);  
    $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", $obj.name);    
    $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()  
    $cmd.Parameters.clear();  
}  
$conn.Close()
```

The problem is this line:

```
$JSONResult | Select date, name Where name = 'Christmas Day'
```

Can someone help me understand how to make a WHERE clause work here?

I have been working using the code provided.  The code runs without errors, but the WHERE clause seemingly is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the `Where-Object` cmdlet:

```
$JSONResult = $JSONResult | Select date, name | Where name -eq 'Christmas Day'
```

PowerShell uses the syntax `-<op>` for its operators, hence `-eq` rather than `=`.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to keep in mind as you filter in PowerShell is that piping your results to `Where-Object` (or using the alias `where`) outputs ALL the results of any given cmdlet before filtering. Some cmdlets have a `-Filter` parameter you can use to narrow the results down as the cmdlet processes, which will speed up your scripts a bit.

In this case, unfortunately, neither `Invoke-WebRequest` or `ConvertFrom-Json` support the `-Filter` parameter but keep an eye out as you continue scripting and give it a try.